# Неправильно запускается функция DLL через CMD при помощи RUNDLL32.exe

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

Проблема в следующем:

Задача запустить функцию DLL в командной строке, при вызове пользователь должен вводить размер массива, который заполняется рандомными значениями, количество потоков и приоритетность потоков. При запуске окно появляется но ничего нельзя ввести.

Сама DLL рабочая, использовалась при статическом и динамическом подключении, но нужно запустить функцию через консоль.

Также один человек сказал, что проблема в том что я не являюсь абсолютным администратором

```
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void lab4()
{
    AllocConsole();

    freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPTSTR)module, MAXMODULE);
    cout << "\n\nThis function was called from "
        << module
        << endl << endl;

    srand(time(NULL));
    int arrSize;
    int numOfThreads;
    int numOfPriority;

    GetModuleFileName(NULL, (LPTSTR)module, MAXMODULE);

    HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);         

    if (hMutex == NULL)
    {
        printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    DWORD thread_priority;
    DWORD thread_ID;

    cout << "Array size: "; cin >> arrSize;
    cout << "Num of Threads: "; cin >> numOfThreads;
    cout << "NumOfPriority (0-IDLE; 1-LOWEST; 2-NORMAL; 3-HIGHEST; 4-TIME_CRITICAL):"; cin >> numOfPriority;

    if (numOfPriority == 0)thread_priority = THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE;
    else if (numOfPriority == 1)thread_priority = THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST;
    else if (numOfPriority == 2)thread_priority = THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL;
    else if (numOfPriority == 3)thread_priority = THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST;
    else if (numOfPriority == 4)thread_priority = THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL;

    HANDLE *hThr = new HANDLE[numOfThreads];   

    threadParam *MyParam = new threadParam[numOfThreads]; 


    int *MyArray = new int[arrSize]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)MyArray[i] = 1 + rand() % 100; 

    int step = arrSize / numOfThreads;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {

        MyParam[i].ptr = MyArray;
        MyParam[i].indexStart = i * step;
        MyParam[i].indexEnd = i * step + step - 1;
        MyParam[i].length = arrSize;
        if (i == numOfThreads - 1)MyParam[i].indexEnd = arrSize - 1;

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE); 
        hThr[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SortArray, (PVOID)&MyParam[i], CREATE_SUSPENDED, &thread_ID);
        SetThreadPriority(hThr[i], thread_priority);
        ResumeThread(hThr[i]);
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        Sleep(100);

    }
```

[image: скриншот запуска dll]

Comment: `freopen_s((FILE**)stdout, ...` - что это??? Если уж идти по этому пути, то наверное должно быть `freopen_s(&stdout, ...`? Подозреваю. что вы сначала написали `freopen_s(stdout, ...`, вас компилятор ткнул носом в ошибку несоответствия типов, а вы решили, недолго думая, просто заткнуть ему глотку при помощи `(FILE **)`. Получилась чушь.

Comment: @AnT хорошо, дело только в этом?

Comment: stdin сам себя не перенаправит